# Init & update submodules with git-lfs include

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-lfs

I'm making a test for Windows, so I want to restrict some lfs files that is not necessary in submodules.

When I try `git submodule update --init --recursive`, it pulls all lfs files.
Running `git config lfs.fetchinclude "*.lib"` before update submodule doesn't pull any lfs files at all,
and `git config lfs.fetchexclude "*.a,*.so"` before update submodule pulls all lfs files.

I don't want to specify a submodule to restrict lfs files, since it's not open to changes.
How can I do this?